# Uber Driver API: Test Accounts

Tags: uber-api

Are there test accounts available in the Uber Driver API to authenticate our app and receive dummy data from the API?

The sandbox service isn't what we need. As the developer a project with Uber we don't have an active driver account to test.

Comment: I would suggest contacting Uber for that…!?

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no way to create dummy accounts. For testing we only have the sandbox or a live Driver account. We hope to provide this feature in the future but do not have it available at this time.